# Execution failed for task ':app:bintrayUpload' and Execution failed for task ':app:bintrayPublish'

Tags: android, bintray

> Cannot cast object 'task ':bintrayUpload'' with class 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask_Decorated' to class 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask'
>
> Cannot cast object 'task ':asista-ui:bintrayUpload'' with class 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask_Decorated' to class 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New Dependency added to My project and this dependency was writted in kotlin but i am Using language for Java.So,My App Displayed a error Message for Adding a Kotlin Version.I Am added a Kotlin Version 1.0.50 something.**
So I Solved this Error For Following->
**Remove the Kotlin Version and Its using Place and Its Solved..And Update your gradle built version for Latest...**

**Another Error For Displayed in bintrayPublish failed**
this error solved for using this Method->
**Change bintray  latest Version.(E.g:1.8.4) **